# Why are EPS files not showing up when using XeLatex?

Tags: graphics, xetex, miktex, eps

This code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{tiger}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

is producing a blank page for me.

log output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.9.6)  9 SEP 2016 16:45
entering extended mode
**C:/projects/thesis/foo-thesis.tex
(C:/projects/thesis/foo-thesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2016/07/11 v4.10 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (L3/RRM/JK)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
) (foo-thesis.aux)
\openout1 = `foo-thesis.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
File: tiger.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <tiger.eps>
Overfull \hbox (205.05501pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--12
[][] 
 []


LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 38.1975pt on input line 12.

[1] (foo-thesis.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 599 strings out of 428408
 6776 string characters out of 3160625
 58967 words of memory out of 3000000
 4061 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,19p,293b,236s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on foo-thesis.pdf (1 page).
```

the overfull hbox shouldn't be the problem, right?

some notes:

- i tried this with an eps exported with libreoffice draw and two random eps files pulled from the internet.
- if i have more text in there, it looks like it's actually reserving
  the correct space for the graphic, but putting nothing in it.
- png files work fine.
- in dvipdfmx.cfg, mgs.exe is enabled, not rungs or eps2pdf.
- having said that, there is no conversion output file of any kind visible anywhere.
- using e.g. `[width=5cm]` gets rid of the warnings but still, nothing shows up.

Comment: You get an `Overfull \hbox` with that code you posted?

Comment: `Float too large for page ...`?

Comment: Works for me (of course the box is overfull), but I'm not on MiKTeX.

Comment: @Alenanno yes, depending on the graphic that i include of course.

Comment: @cfr that's what it says, yes, but that shouldn't stop it from displaying *something* as far as i know.

Comment: Can you try with `\includegraphics[width=5cm]{tiger.eps}`?

Comment: It compiles fine with MiKTeX 64-bit.

Comment: @egreg doesn't change anything (well, the warnings of course are gone)

Comment: @Bernard you also see the actual figure in the output?

Comment: Yes. Of course it overflows into the margin; but I see it.

Comment: Well, it depends how much too big it is. White space can look like a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Running xetex in the command line gave me the following output:

```
<snip>
(foo-thesis.aux) )stdin -> foo-thesis.pdf
[1
xdvipdfmx:warning: No image converter available for converting file "./graphics/Lighting_pipeline_concept_rough.eps" to PDF format.
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please check if you have 'D' option in config file.
xdvipdfmx:warning: pdf: image inclusion failed for "graphics/Lighting_pipeline_concept_rough.eps".
xdvipdfmx:warning: Failed to read image file: graphics/Lighting_pipeline_concept_rough.eps
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting special command PSfile (ps:) failed.
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 630.034)" (in PDF)
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> xxx "PSfile="graphics/Lighting_pipeline_concept_rough.eps" llx=0 lly"
<snip>
```

which was not shown in the log i saw. i don't know what causes the incomplete log, but i filed a bug in atom-latex which i used: https://github.com/thomasjo/atom-latex/issues/212

Regarding the actual problem:

Besides the `dvipdfmx.cfg` in `C:\Program Files` Miktex seems to put another `dvipdfmx.cfg` into the ProgramData directory. It was pretty empty (e.g. didn't contain the D option) and apparently completely overwrites the one in Program Files. Removing that file in ProgramData fixed the problem. I filed https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2527/ for this.

Comment: Given that your original code used `tiger`, it isn't surprising it didn't show these errors. It makes this much, much easier if the code you post produces the errors you report.

Comment: @cfr as i said i tried this with multiple eps files to rule out a problem with a specific file. it was the same problem with all the files, and the same solution with all the files.